# Как настроить способ отображения для конкретного типа материала Drupal в файле ds-2col?

Tags: php, drupal

В настройках отображения типа материала нужно вывести две сложенные колонки, то есть шапка, правая, левая, подвал.
Сейчас у этих четырех блоков одно общее обрамление. Но **мне нужно сделать, нужно добавить обрамление вокруг правой и левой колонки, то сделать вокруг них блок**

В настройках написано что:
Шаблон по умолчанию, расположен по адресу sites/all/modules/ds/layouts/ds_2col_stacked

- ds-2col-stacked--node.tpl.php
- ds-2col-stacked--node-teaser.tpl.php
- ds-2col-stacked--node-our-works.tpl.php
- ds-2col-stacked--node-our-works-teaser.tpl.php

выбираю последний вариант, копирую оригинал файла **ds-2col-stacked--node.tpl.php**  и вставлю с названием последнего варианта **(ds-2col-stacked--node-our-works-teaser.tpl.php**), то есть в папке у меня уже 2 файла лежит, один оригинал, и другой для моего случая.
Теперь по-хорошему, если выбрать две сложенные колонки у этого типа материала, должне включиться мой файл, но ничего не происходит, в коде блок не появился. Закомментировал, оригинал, дабы проверить, мой файл не сработал.

В самом коде добавил первую и последнюю строку, div начало и конец

```
    <div class='hidden'>
    <<?php print $left_wrapper ?> class="group-left<?php print $left_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $left; ?>
    </<?php print $left_wrapper ?>>

    <<?php print $right_wrapper ?> class="group-right<?php print $right_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $right; ?>
    </<?php print $right_wrapper ?>>
    </div>
```

Comment: Кеш пробовали сбрасывать? Обычно это решение, если не подхватывается какой-то файл темы, или изменения в теме.

Comment: Вопрос решил, файл нужно было не в модуль а в тему кидать